# I don't have no time

Tags: meaning

Does that mean that "I don't have any time" or "I have time" because there are two no's there?

Comment: Literally, it means  that "*you have time*", but the actual meaning is: *I don't have any time*

Comment: ***These are all examples of double negatives***, which are regarded as non-standard usage in formal spoken and written English, but ***which are very common in informal speech, song lyrics, etc***. https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/02/09/grammar-myths-3/